# how does a function changes the value of a variable outside its scope? Python

Tags: python

i was coding this code and noticed something weird, after my function has been called on the variable, the value of the variable gets changed although **its outside of the functions scope**, how exactly is this happening?

```
def test(my_list):
  if 11 in my_list and sum(my_list) > 21:
    my_list.remove(11)
    my_list.append(1)
  return sum(my_list)


ca = [11,11]
print(test(ca))
print(ca)
```

the above code results to:

```
12
[11, 1]
```

Comment: read about garbage collection and how scopes work and stuff

Comment: @SuperStew Doesn't make sense here. Python variables and function arguments are always references (pointers) to objects. Therefore there is only one list object used and modified in this code.

Comment: @SuperStew so you are saying this is normal? apparently it only works on lists, when i pass anything else rather than lists, this doesnt happen, but when its a list, the variable outside gets changed.

Comment: It would work with dicts too and with other objects which can be modified (are "mutable"). Numbers, strings and tuples are immutable.

Comment: Hi @blackbox. When you pass so-called _primitive_ types, they're just copied and not changed outside. Primitive types like numbers. When you pass object types, they will get modified outside. Try the same thing with a dictionary.

Comment: @MichaelButscher then how come its only working on lists? if what you say is true, shouldnt it work on other types of variables? but only the lists changes like this.

Comment: @Lagerbaer, Python has no primitive types, everything is an object.

Comment: @blackbox you're not changing the list (try it) but the content of a list, that is other python object referred by the list.

Comment: hi @Lagerbaer, i tried it with a Dict and it didnt work. can you provide me with an example?

Answer (score 3):

Because my_list is a list, a mutable object.

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-did-changing-list-y-also-change-list-x

> In other words:
>
> - If we have a mutable object (list, dict, set, etc.), we can use some specific operations to mutate it and all the variables that refer
>   to it will see the change.
> - If we have an immutable object (str, int, tuple, etc.), all the variables that refer to it will always see the same value, but
>   operations that transform that value into a new value always return a
>   new object.

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-write-a-function-with-output-parameters-call-by-reference

```
3. By passing a mutable (changeable in-place) object:
>>>

>>> def func2(a):
...     a[0] = 'new-value'     # 'a' references a mutable list
...     a[1] = a[1] + 1        # changes a shared object
...
>>> args = ['old-value', 99]
>>> func2(args)
>>> args
['new-value', 100]
```

You can change the content of a list, but not a list itself. For example:

```
>>> def test(my_mutable):
...  my_mutable = [1]
...  print(my_mutable)
... 
>>> my_mutable = [2]
>>> test(my_mutable)
[1]
>>> my_mutable
[2]
```

You can do the same with dict:

```
>>> ca = {11: 11, 12: 12}
>>> def test(my_dict):
...  if 11 in my_dict and sum(my_dict.values()) > 21:
...    del my_dict[11]
...    my_dict[1] = 1
...  return sum(my_dict.values())
... 
>>> test(ca)
13
>>> ca
{12: 12, 1: 1}
```

Comment: thanks for the very good help. so by passing an object, i can change the value of the object, and thats not a problem with the scopes, right?

Comment: You cannot change the object. Try do delete it, for example. You can change the content referred by a mutable. I'll add an example with dict

Comment: I've added an example tryng to change a mutable, which will not work outside the scope of the function.