# nested function in Python where the outer variable is changed when it is used as input and been sorted in inner function

Tags: python, function, scope

I have a question regarding the modification of nested function in python. In the following code, I found that varible *a* in the outer function has been changed through inner function *a.sort()*. Why this happens and how to avoid the bug?

```
def outer():
    a = [2,3,1]
    def inner(a):
        a.sort()
    inner(a)
    return a
outer()

output: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: The `a` in `inner()` refers to exactly the same list as the `a` in `outer()` - Python is not in the habit of making copies of objects unless this was explicitly requested.  If you want `inner()` to work on a different list, pass `a.copy()` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted()` function instead of `sort` method

```
def outer():
    a = [2,3,1]
    def inner(a):
        sorted(a)
    inner(a)
    return a
outer()
```

Comment: thanks! May I know why the outer variables can be modified? Are they supposed to be not changed?

Comment: You don't modify a variable but the mutable object to which the variable name is associated. You can further read [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68118045/how-does-a-function-changes-the-value-of-a-variable-outside-its-scope-python) for example.

Comment: Your shared post is super helpful! Thanks a lot!